# How to render array to select option vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i have array like this from API:

```
{"select1":"Select 1","select2":"Select 2","select3":"Select 3"}
```

i want to render this array to `option` list select.

i have tried like this but i dont know how to fill the value and text.
[image]

Comment: what's the name of that font? is it vscode?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to the documentation, `v-for` allows you to iterate through the properties of an object.

In this case, your object is an associative array called `reasons`. This means, that this array has a list of *keys* and *values*. The first pair (*key*:*value*) is `"select1"` and `"Select 1"` respectively.

**How to render the *values* of these pairs?**

Well, to extract the first item `"Select 1"` we need to declare a pair of alias like `key` and `item` and then render it by interpolation using  `{{...}}` in this case the `item` alias as shown in this code sample:

```js
var selector = new Vue({
  el: '#selector',
  data: {
    selected: '',
    reasons: {
      "select1": "Select 1",
      "select2": "Select 2",
      "select3": "Select 3",
      "select4": "Select 4",
      "select5": "Select 5",
      "select6": "Select 6",
      "select7": "Select 7"
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="selector">
  <select v-model="selected">
    <option v-for="(item, key) in reasons" :value="key">
      {{item}}
    </option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <br>
  <span>Selected: {{ selected }}</span>
</div>
```

**Update**

Remember that the HTML tag `select` uses the `option` tag for each item of the list. Now, this `option` tag has a `value` parameter  and a `text` like in this structure:

```
<select>
  <option value="select1">Select 1</option>
  ...
  <option value="select7">Select 7</option>
</select>
```

So, we need to assign each `key` of the array reasons to each `value` parameter of the `option` tag and render the `value` of the array reasons as the text of the `option` tag.

```
<option v-for="(item, key) in reasons" :value="key">
  {{item}}
</option>
```

Also, do not forget about `v-model` directive, which creates two-way data bindings on form input, textarea, and select elements. This means, it automatically picks the correct way to update the element based on the input type. We can achieve this by adding `selected` to the `data` definition in the `Vue` instance creation and adding `v-model="selected"` to the `select` tag.

Comment: How can I use the select htnl attribute to pick a default option in my options iteration?
I added this:
```<option v-bind: selected="item.id === 1" v-for="item in thirdOptions">{{item.name}}</option>```

Answer (score 2):

You should look over the [documentation for list rendering an object](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Object-v-for).

```
  <select>
    <option v-for="(reason, key) in reasons" 
            :value="key"
            :key="key">
      {{reason}}
    </option>
  </select>
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/BRoKjq?editors=1010).